# Он подождал ещё неделю, и во второй раз позвонил в областной центр. Как объяснить запятую?

Tags: пунктуация, союзы, запятые, однородые, сказуемые

Он подождал ещё неделю, и во второй раз позвонил в областной центр. Как объяснить запятую?

- Запятая напрашивается в предложение, но по сути разделяются однородные сказуемые, соединенные союзом **и**, что считается ошибкой. Как можно аргументировать здесь запятую: наличие паузы, наличие добавочного характера сообщения или чем-то другим?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Он подождал ещё неделю, и (потом) во второй раз позвонил в областной центр.**

Можно сказать, что союз И ― присоединительный, делается пауза.

В действительности нет тесной связи однородных сказуемых, они разделены второстепенными членами, и предложение ближе к ССП.

Comment: Спасибо за ответ! А что восстановлено в скобках -- и (потом)? У Розенталя как присоединительные слова указаны "и притом", "и" (в зн. "и притом"), но здесь они не подходят: Он подождал ещё неделю, и притом во второй раз позвонил в областной центр. Всегда ли наличие второстепенных членов ослабляет связь однородных сказуемых и даёт право квалифицировать предложение как ССП?

Comment: 1) Наши правила слишком формальны, различение ССП и однородных сказуемых - это не их тема, а тема грамматики.  Я объяснила, почему нужна пауза и нет тесной связи в данном случае. Хотя временнОе наречие   "потом"  отсутствует, но оно подразумевается: действия выполнены не сразу.  А если не поставить запятую, то они будут читаться в одну фразу, то есть следовать одно за другим.  2) В правилах же (для официального объяснения) можно сослаться на присоединительный характер союза, там эта тема есть.